# select searchview android not with the icon

Tags: java, android, searchview

I have a view that goes like this :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/searchPart"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="@drawable/moviesearch"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/query"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="90"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:queryHint="Enter query :" >
    </SearchView>
</LinearLayout>
```

But to select do a search with the searchview widget we must tap on the search icon, and not anywhere else. Is there a way to bypass that by taping on the entire frame ?

Answer (score 3):

A little late but i hope it helps someone.

To show the SerchView always opened add this in your layout file:

```
android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
```

If you want to set it programatically try this:

```
YourSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

Otherwise, use `true` as parameter value.